# C# Cast Enumerable.Iterator to known List<Object> at run time

Tags: c#, list, casting, enumerable, custom-object

I have a method where I can only retrieve the object type at runtime. I tried to cast it to a list of known object, but I failed.

```
  private string outputParamForListOrDict(IMethodReturn returnValue)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String outputString = string.Empty;

        switch (returnValue.ReturnValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name)
        {       

            case nameof(ViewDocumentReport):

                List<ViewDocumentReport> _viewDocumentParam = (List<ViewDocumentReport>)returnValue.ReturnValue;

                //process the data here........

                return sb.ToString();

            //Other object cases

         }
    }
```

I got an exception below:

```
"Unable to cast object of type >'<TakeIterator>d__25`1[ezAcquire.RMS.Model.ViewModels.ViewDocumentReport]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ezAcquire.RMS.Model.ViewModels.ViewDocumentReport]'."}
```

I put a breakpoint in debug mode.
My returnValue.ReturnValue is of [image: System.Linq.Enumrable.<TakeIterator>]

and if I expand I can see there a list of List.

[image: List<ViewDocumentREport>]

can someone explain to me what is the d_25 meant, and advice me on how should I cast it correctly during runtime?

Thanks

Comment: returnValue.ReturnValue is of object type, it doesn't have a .Cast method.

Check the link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I am using framework 4.6.2, do you come from different version ?

Comment: Nope, I just didn't know the details of your model. You may want to cast to `IEnumerable<ViewDocumentReport>` before trying to make it a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're quite sure your object is an IEnumerable of a type you know, you can cast the object to the `IEnumerable<T>` before performing a `ToList`.

```
public class Test {

}

void Main()
{
    object x = Enumerable.Range(0,100).Select(_ => new Test()).Take(15);
    List<Test> fail = (List<Test>)x; // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>d__25`1[UserQuery+Test]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserQuery+Test]'.
    List<Test> pass = ((IEnumerable<Test>)x).ToList(); // No problem
}
```

Casting directly from `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` is not a valid cast, as you've encountered. You'll need to cast your `object` to an `IEnumerable` before either feeding it into a `List<T>` constructor or using Linq's `ToList` method.

Comment: You are spot on, i will mark this as the correct answer.